# How to get element under mouse cursor while dragging another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I googled and found several answers but they was all about click or mousemove events which are not suitable for my question.

Basically I allow users to drag an item from a list and drop it on a folder in another list and I want to highlight element (in the folder list) whenever an item is dragging over it. Listening to mouseenter and mouseleave events on the folder list won't work. I tried with document.elementFromPoint in the dragging event (jQuery UI's Draggable drag) but unfortunately it returns the helper element instead of the element in the folder list. I think it's correct behavior since document.elementFromPoint returns the top most element under mouse cursor. But it doesn't solve my problem :(.

```
    $("#filelist li").draggable({
        helper: "clone",
        drag: function (event, ui) {
            console.log(event.pageX, event.pageY);

            var element = document.elementFromPoint(event.pageX, event.pageY);

            // element is helper element, instead of actual element under cursor which I want.
        }
    });
    $("#folderlist").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
        }
    });
    // These mouse events won't be triggered while dragging an item.
    $("#folderlist").on({
        "mouseenter": function (event) {
            this.style.backgroundColor = "#1c70cf";
        },
        "mouseleave": function (event) {
            this.style.backgroundColor = "";
        }
    }, "li");
```

Comment: what is the `#folderlist`? you could use the `dragover`/`dragleave` events

Comment: @Luizgrs I think I said I wanted to highlight items in the folder list, not folder list element itself. Those events are raised once when mouse enter/leave droppable target.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the droppable has an hover function. http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#visual-feedback

```
$("#folderlist").droppable({
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
    }
});
```

Then add this to your css :

```
.ui-state-hover
{
    background-color: #1c70cf;
}
```

Comment: You can get even more fine-grained control on it with [the `over` event handler](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-over). The downside is that in either case, you need to make the `#folderlist li`s droppable, not the `#folderlist`

Comment: @Flipke I want to highlight LIs, not UL (a droppable target). And It's not an issue if I make LIs are droppable.

Comment: Well then problem solved, just change to this :
$("#folderlist li").droppable instead of $("#folderlist").droppable