# Get under mouse - current DOM element obj [while event-resize ] jQuery-ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

i have set a function to track mouse events on `document`, even though i only need 
the mouse specifically for on re-size detection purpose at-least at this point ...

```
var BoolMouseDown = false;
var BoolResizing = false;
document.body.onmousedown = function () {
    BoolMouseDown = true;
};
document.body.onmouseup = function () {
    BoolMouseDown = false;
};
```

**on the ui**

sideNote: objective is to get data of every element under mouse so it could transform into a new(div) part which survived the conqueror

```
// called function on resiz event

var ValueCurSourceCellId = "";
var ValueCurDestCellId = "";
function CurCellIdSet(val) {
     if (BoolMouseDown) {
        ValueCurDestCellId = val;
        BoolMouseDown = false;
    }
    else {
        if (BoolResizing) {
            ValueCurDestCellId = val;
        }
        ValueCurSourceCellId = val;
    }
}


var BoolHasCollided  = false;
$(gitem11)
.mouseover(function () {
   //cur mouse over = attribute of html-imput-hidden( curMoRszr="")
   if (BoolMouseDown) return;//so if its Mouse Down - don't collect underlying element data

   $elmHidData1.attr('curMoRszr', $(this).attr('id'));
   CurCellIdSet($(this).attr('id'));
})
.mousedown(function () {
   BoolMouseDown = true;
   $elmHidData1.attr('curMoRszr', $(this).attr('id'));
   CurCellIdSet($(this).attr('id'));
})
.mouseup(function () {
   BoolMouseDown = false;
   CurCellIdSet($(this).attr('id'));
})
.resizable({

   handles: "e, s", ghost: true,
   start: 
       // here 11 is the accident producer, 21 is the victim.
       function () {
           console.log("resize started");
           curg21initialpositionTop = $curg21.offset().top;
           curg11initialpositionTop = $curg11.offset().top;
           curg11initialHeight = $curg11.css("height").substring(0, 2);
   },

   resize: 

        function (event, ui) {

             var data1id = $elmHidData1.attr('curMoRszr');
             if (ui.size.height + curg11initialpositionTop > curg21initialpositionTop && ui.size.height + curg11initialpositionTop < curg21initialpositionTop + 50 + gap)
             {
                setRszble($curg11, $curg21);
                BoolHasCollided  = true;
             }

             $(gitem31).text("p: " + ui.size.height + "curg21initialuiposition:" + curg21initialuiposition + ", " + ui.position.top);
       },
       stop:
      // function to conclude the accident, give the new partial div a position and size 
});
```

while asking here on SO, the closest post i have found is [This^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26712314/how-to-get-element-under-mouse-cursor-while-dragging-another-element)

what is the proper way to collect the data on resize Event?

Comment: I would use the `resize` event: resize: function(e, ui){ var x = e.clientX; var y = e.clientY; }`

Comment: @Twisty thanks for your suggestion, I will give it a try..

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you can do:

`document.elementFromPoint(x, y);`

where x and y will be the mouse position (I assume you can get that pointer position yourself)

From there you can get the data off the element you need.